# Filter my Dictonary where the key = a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary

I have written following code:

```
if(True):
        List = df['Column1'].unique()
        for i in range(len(List)):
This does not work -->  df_sc.key == List[i] <-- This does not work
            df_List = df[df['Column1'] == List[i]]
            outputFileName = 'Auswertung_' + List[i].replace('.', '-') + '.xlsx'
            analyze_dataframe(df_List, df_sc ,outputFileName)
```

df_sc is a dictonary which contains a key and value (the values are dataframes). What I want to do is to filter the dictonary where the key = List[i].

But my code is not working.

Comment: Please provide an example of the dataframe too.

Comment: You don't "filter" dictionaries by a key. The point of using a dictionary is to have direct access to individual keys. Just do `df_sc[List[i]]`

Comment: I forget to mention that the keys of my dictonary are the same as the values in column1 of my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter a dictionary. I guess one way to do it is, use that `dict` as source of a DataFrame, `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dict)
```

That way, you can use your `list` to filter it by using the `.isin()` method:

```
df = df.loc[df['column to filter with your list'].isin(your_list_source_for_filtering)]
```

That new `df` now will only contain the columns and rows from your original `df` that satisfies the value of your `your_list_source_for_filtering` list checked in the `'column to filter with your list'` column values.

Using this, you don't have to do a crude loop.

Hope this helps :)).

Comment: You can however insist on doing the "filtering" on your dictionary, but it won't be "filtering" as much as parsing every key and checking if it exists in your `filter_list` if `true` append its value on a list, else, move to the next key.